# checking the database query ,always shows (database query failed)

Tags: php, database, mysqli

i'm in a middle of making a query with my new database and i keep getting the message (Database query failed) through the code below:

```
      <?php
    //create a database connection
    $dbhost= "localhost";
    $dbname= "widget_corp";
    $connection=mysqli_connect($dbhost , $dbname);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("Database connection failed :" . mysqli_connect_error ."(". mysqli_connect_errno .")");
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    //perform a database query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM subjects";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection ,$query);

    if (!$result){
        die("Database query failed.");
    }

?>
```

please advise

Comment: Aside from the fact that you don't send a username or password to `mysqli_connect`, is there a `subjects` table in `widget_corp`?

Comment: And what would be useful is checking why it failed: `printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing in a username or password. mysqli_connect() requires four parameters to be passed in : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

You're only passing in a host and database name.